# Stopping ios 7 remote notification sound

Tags: ios7, apple-push-notifications

In iOS 7, when a user swipes one of my notifications from the lockscreen and is taken to my app, the notification sound keeps playing (unlike iOS 6). Is there any way to programmatically stop that sound when my app launches in iOS 7?

NOTE: see the accepted answer for a shoddy workaround.

Comment: On my side, `setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0` didn't work.
Note that this seems to be a bug: https://devforums.apple.com/message/888091 But Apple didn't communicate on this.

Comment: you might want to try `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 1]; [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];`, thats actually what I am doing

Comment: That did the trick yeah. What I bountied is a real solution, though.. This feels more like a bad workaround.

Comment: oh I'm with you I'd love to know a real solution as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug on apple's end after reading the dev forum link you posted, Apple doesn't let you see other people's bug reports - they use the fact that multiple people are reporting the same bug to assign priority to bugs, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144873/can-i-browse-other-peoples-apple-bug-reports. You may want to file a duplicate bug report, as I have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug on Apple's end, see [devforums.apple.com/message/888091](http://devforums.apple.com/message/888091) (thanks Gui13). File a duplicate bug report to get Apple to pay attention to it, as [that is how Apple assigns priority to bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144873/can-i-browse-other-peoples-apple-bug-reports). In the meantime, the following will work but will also clear all of your notifications in the notification center, which of course is a shoddy workaround, but in my case is worth it until this gets fixed:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 1];    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
```

Comment: Where do you have to put this code to make it happen?
I pasted this code in : 
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
But the notification sound keeps on going?!?

Comment: Are you trying to stop the sound for the remote notification? if so `didReceiveLocalNotification` is, like it says, only for *local* notifications. Read up on how to handle remote notifications as theres a bit to it, but in short you can put it in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: Yes I am putting it in the DidReceiveLocalNotification and yet the sound is not stopping. Any suggestions please?

Comment: I remember reading that in some cases `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called instead, try putting it there as well?

Comment: This workaround seems to be working when the local notification has been triggered by **PUSH** only, does not work unfortunately when the notification has been triggered by the app itself :(

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't help by using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 1];    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
```

after entering the app by clicking the notification.

I have solved this problem by sending another empty notification when dealing with the notification with sound:

```
if (notification.soundName != nil) {
    if (IS_IOS7) {
        UILocalNotification *emptyNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        emptyNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        emptyNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        emptyNotification.alertBody = @"";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:emptyNotification];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 7, the accepted answer may be the only viable option. For developers who have come here that can support a minimum of **iOS 10**, this works.

You can remove all notifications from Notification Center by calling

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
```

This has a very similar affect as the accepted answer: the audio stops playing and all the notifications are removed from Notification Center.

An improved solution is to use

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [String])
```

This stops the audio for only the given notifications, and removes them from Notification Center.

To get the ids for all the delivered notifications, use

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications { notifications in
  let ids = notifications.map { $0.request.identifier }
}
```