# UILocalNotification doesn't stop the sound when the application is brought to foreground by sliding on the alert

Tags: ios, ios7

When my application receives a network messages in the background, it create a UILocalNotification with sound and invokes the presentLocalNotificationNow.

```
    UILocalNotification* localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: \r%@ \r%@", NSLocalizedString(@"XXXXXXXXXXX", nil), XXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXX];
    localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View", nil);

    localNotif.soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", XXXXTONE_LONGVERSION_FILENAME, XXXXTONE_FILENAME_EXT];
    [[UIApplication sharedInstance] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
```

This alert is shown with sound as expected. But I have trouble stopping the sound in some cases.

1) When there is screen lock and this local notification alert is shown:

- if the user unlocks the screen by sliding on the alert, the sound does NOT stop.
- if the user unlocks the screen by sliding "> slide to unlock", it does stop the sound.

2) When the application is background with out screen lock, the alert sound stops normally upon application coming foreground.

I do cancel the scheduled local notifications when app comes foreground in didReceiveLocalNotification and applicationDidBecomeActive.

```
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    [application cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Comment: Off topic here, nothing to do with your problem, but how did you get your app to receive a network message when your application was in the background? is it a network message that was received only within the first few minutes of the application being in the background?

Comment: it is a 'voip' application

Comment: I noticed that the problem always occurs with Touch ID (e.g. on an iPhone 5s). App is the foreground or in the background. Device is locked. Notification is shown on the lock screen. User unlocks using Touch ID  (NOT by sliding the notification or manually entering the lock code). Then user opens the app, the sound does NOT stop.

Comment: I have exactly the same bug here :( is it really a known iOS7 ? (still KO on iOS7.1.2)

Answer (score 5):

<s>It's a known bug of iOS7 which is annoying as hell.

You'll have the exact same problem if you use remote notifications.</s>

The workaround for this is to change the application badge count twice, with at least a step to the value 0.
I have this method in my app for that:

```
- (void)fixRing{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        // iOS7 fix for notification sound not stopping.
        // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124882/stopping-ios-7-remote-notification-sound
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 1];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
    }
}
```

<s>Don't forget to update the badge count to the real value sometimes after.</s>

EDIT:
Actually, this doesn't work for *local* notifications, but only for remote (push) notifications. `[application cancelAllLocalNotifications];` doesn't work, neither does `[application cancelLocalNotification:notif];`...
This is a bug that I've reported to Apple, and is in "process" at the time of writing.
I've tried plenty of workarounds (push a notif with a small sound to *erase* the long sound, use a timer and reiterate the notification with a shorter sound instead of letting it linger for 30s, etc..) but none worked.

Note that Google Hangout seems to suffer from this problem as well.. so I guess there's no real solution.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on my iPhone 5 running iOS 7.1.

Comment: Can you confirm on which device and with which particular version this works?

Comment: @Gui13 Is there still no solution for this problem? I should figure this out :(

Comment: Alas no. Internally with my coworkers, we think that Apple want to ditch this 30s capability, because it is only useful for VoIP apps. Maybe they will propose something more substantial (call view like for the GSM calls?? pleaaaaase). Or more probably remove it..

Answer (score 1):

In your `AppDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` you get your Notification like that:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotif) {
    // do something with it
}
```

Check, if you can stop the alert from there with `cancelLocalNotification:`

Comment: Yes, I am cancelling the local notifications in 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions'.

Comment: is the object null? If yes, you might get it in `receivedLocalNotification` because your app is still running with this voip-story?

Comment: Basically app is running all the time but it was in background and there is screen lock. So due to the UILocalNotification alert, when the slides by using the alert, the app goes into applicationWillEnterForeground followed by didReceiveLocalNotification followed by applicationDidBecomeActive. I am cancelling all the local notifications in the didReceiveLocalNotification.