# iOS hide Sound option in Notification Centre

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm using a push notification with sound data.

Initially I want the notification to play the sound. But now I don't want to play the sound in the push notification any more. so when registering the remote notification, I commented out the TypeSound... (Server side still send sound data in notification payload though)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                                           // UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                                                           UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

And.. I still get the sound playing... I don't know why is it so?

And.. if I don't include the sound in push notification, neither do I register with TypeSound... will the Sound option still show in Notification Centre?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124882/stopping-ios-7-remote-notification-sound

Comment: that's not what I mean.. I don't want the sound at all from the very beginning...

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleaned the project before running it again after commenting out UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound?

Comment: Not yet...but I realise if I install the app from XCode, the Allow Push Notification message is never shown... it only works if installing from TestFlight.

Comment: Why not clean the app before creating the archive, then see it the sound is still played after installing from TestFlight?

Comment: can I test it without TestFlight? just installing from XCode? I cleaned and ran. doesn't help

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used TestFlight, so don't know the process of getting the app onto the device.